# I found 404 Not Found when I installed npm package from local directory even packege exist in nodemodules

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I installed a npm package from a local directory. The package installed and is present in the `node_modules` directory.

But when I access the package it’s showing me error:

> `404 not found`

Can any one suggest to me how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean with `But when I access the package`? How do you try to access the package?

Comment: Means when i access from browser something like that: "http://192.168.0.0.1/nelson/views/node_modules/core-libs/lib/package.json"
It gives me 404.Note: This module i installed locally from file.
But when i access another modules from different folder it accessible

Answer (score 0):

add registry=https://yarn.npmjs.org to file ~/.npmrc.This probably could solve the problem. Also it would be better if you send a screenshot or snippet of the error.